# tinymce(4.2.5) allow all html tag, class and style

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

```
tinymce.init({
    language: "ja",
    plugins: ["code link"],
    selector: ".tiny-mce",
    valid_elements: '*[*​]',
    extended_valid_elements: '*[*​]',

    valid_children: {'*':'*'},
    valid_classes: {'*':'*'},
    valid_styles: {'*':'*'},

    toolbar: " bold underline | formatselect | link unlink | code",
    menubar: false,
    height: 500,
    block_formats: "Paragraph=p;Heading 1=h4;Heading 2=h5;Heading 3=h6"
});
```

I'd like to allow all html tag, class and style in tinymce4.
Allowing HTML tag can work.
But class and style can't.

Thanks in advance.

I tried `valid_elements: '*[class|style​]'`. And input is below.

```
<iframe src="../../"></iframe>
<script>alert(111)</script>
<style>p{color:#000;}</style>
<i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
```

Output is below.

```
<p><iframe src="../../"></iframe></p>
<script>// <![CDATA[
alert(111)
// ]]></script>
<p><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></p>
```

Style tag was vanished!
what happened to me?

Comment: what about valid_elements: '*[class|style​]', ?

Comment: Thank you for reacting. i tried to do with `valid_elements: '*[class|style​]'`. I need a little more for style tag. Output is above. I would be happy if you could look.

Comment: hmm, script and style tags should better be used inside a head element. the i-tag gets placed inside a paragraph because tinymce uses a root block element. Concerning the script and style tags you might try to explicitly add them to the extended_valid_elements

Comment: style tags add to the `extended_valid_elements` but it didnt work. I decided  to set style by class.  I appreciate your help. thank you!